# Can’t use convmv in right way?

Tags: terminal, finder, file-conversion, encoding

I’m trying to convert name encoding of some path tree with files using convmv utility.

Folders look something like this:

[image]

Some names are typed with transliteration. This files is okay, and I tried to change another filenames.

I find out, that source encoding is CP437 and purpose encoding is CP866.

[image]

When I tried command

```
$ convmv --notest -f cp437 -t cp866 -r * --nosmart
```

I got

```
cp866 doesn't cover all needed characters for: "./103_5 τ¿Γ-¬«ñ«ó ¬απΓ«ú« YouTube-¬á¡á½á.mp4»
```

It’s look like i should convert it from utf-8 to cp437 at first, and it 
was successful,

```
mv "./85_èá¬ ¡Ñ ΓÑα∩Γ∞ ¬«¡óÑαß¿ε ¡á φΓá»Ñ αÑú¿ßΓαáµ¿¿.mp4"  "./85_??? ?? ????? ???????? ?? ?⠯? ॣ????樨.mp4"
mv "./86_èá¬ »«½πτ¿Γ∞ ú«α∩τ¿σ ¬½¿Ñ¡Γ«ó ¡á óδßΓáó¬Ñ.mp4" "./86_??? ??????? ?????? ?????⮢ ?? ???⠢??.mp4"
mv "./87_èá¬ »«ßΓα«¿Γ∞ φΣΣÑ¬Γ¿ó¡δ⌐ email-¼áα¬ÑΓ¿¡ú.mp4" "./87_??? ????ந?? ??䥪⨢?? email-??થ⨭?.mp4"
```

but my source folder becomes 0kb size

[image]

And i cant to open any file in this folders.

Okay, then i tried again

```
 $ convmv --notest -f cp437 -t cp866 -r * --nosmart
```

i got again

```
cp866 doesn't cover all needed characters for: "./103_5 τ¿Γ-¬«ñ«ó ¬απΓ«ú« YouTube-¬á¡á½á.mp4»
```

I find out that i could make it again and again, and result was the same

**What i making wrong?**

Comment: Does it fail for all folders or just for some? Did you check the encoding of the failing names on the website already?

Comment: @nohillside yes, it fail for all folders